# Why does the value of a parameter not change?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, fractions

I need help solving this problem in my mind so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

For example:

```
Enter: 2 3
Output: 4199120/3436544

It should print: 2/3
```

Why is the output different from what I expect?

```
struct Fraction { int x1, x2; };

void function(struct Fraction p, int *d) {
  p.x1=d[0];
  p.x2=d[1];
}

int main() {
  struct Fraction frac;
  int d[2];
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    scanf("%d", &d[i]);
  }
  function(frac, d);
  printf("%d/%d", frac.x1, frac.x2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `raz`? You are passing `frac` in `function` but printing `raz`. If your code compiles, you probably have `raz` defined somewhere and possibly filled with garbage.

Comment: Sorry, It should have written "frac", my fault! It still prints addresses

Answer (score 2):

**Always** pay attention to your compiler warnings.

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:1: warning: ‘frac.x2’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   21 | printf("%d/%d",frac.x1,frac.x2);
```

Your compiler tells you that the `frac` is uninitialized. Why? The `function` was supposed to initialize it, i.e., fill it with data.

However, you are passing it by value to your `function`. Your `function`, when executed, creates a brand new `struct Fraction`, copies the contents of `frac` that you have passed, then does what you expect it to do; fills **its own `struct Fraction p`**, with `d[0]` and `d[1]` and returns, deleting the local variable `struct Fraction p` with it.

The `printf` in the main simply prints the garbage that was in the `frac` to begin with.

Your `function` should modify the actual variable `frac` local to main, hence you need to pass the address of it as:

```
function( &frac, d );
```

And of course the `function` should accept it as such:

```
void function(struct Fraction *p, int *d)
{
    p->x1 = d[0];
    p->x2 = d[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `frac` [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm) to `function` (the link explains why exactly the parameter is not modified). Try:

```
void function(struct Fraction *p, int *d) {
  p->x1=d[0];
  p->x2=d[1];
}

int main() {
  ...
  function(&frac, d);
  printf("%d/%d", frac.x1, frac.x2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to return a struct from the function

```
struct Fraction function(int *d) {
    struct Fraction res;
    res.x1 = d[0];
    res.x2 = d[1];
    //int gcd = calc_gcd(d[0], d[1]); // calc_gcd() calculates the greatest common denominator
                                      // implementation left as an exercise
    //rec.x1 /= gcd;
    //rec.x2 /= gcd;
    return res;
}
```

And then your code would be

```
int main(void) {
    struct Fraction frac;
    int d[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &d[i]); // error checking ommited for brevity
    }
    frac = function(d);
    printf("%d/%d\n", frac.x1, frac.x2);
    return 0;
}
```